# How to get multiple CSS output from tailwind

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I'm using TailwindCSS, I want a separate stylesheet CSS file for each of my web pages. like
about.html - about.min.css
portfolio.html - portfolio.css

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to install TailwindCSS as PostCSS plugin as well as `postcss-import` and `autoprefixer`. Then create postcss.config.js in root directory and add:

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    'postcss-import': {},
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  }
}
```

then you can [add as many css files](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-custom-styles#using-multiple-css-files) as needed in your css directory, albeit with some concerns following [this documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/using-with-preprocessors#build-time-imports)

Keep in mind, you should only use one css for all pages in your web unless you have multiple projects with different styling required.

Answer (score 1):

If using the standalone CLI, open two terminals. In the first, run:

```
./tailwindcss -i about-input.css -o about.min.css --watch --minify
```

on the other terminal, run:

```
./tailwindcss -i portfolio-input.css -o portfolio.css --watch
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix')

mix.postCss('input.css', 'output.css', [
  require('tailwindcss')`enter code here`('./tailwind.config.js'),
  require('autoprefixer')
])
.postCss('input.css', 'output-pdf.css', [
  require('tailwindcss')('./tailwind-custom.config.js'),
  require('autoprefixer')
])
```

Answer (score -4):

First you should ask yourself why do you want to do this? Creating a separate style-sheet for each individual page (home, about, etc) is not really common. The focus is on re-usability and possibly only adding additional styles.

If you are concerned about the file size, then do not integrate Tailwind via CDN but build your own style. Then you have access to the purge function. Purge kicks out all unused styles and the result is a very small CSS file.

Comment: `admin` and `application` for instance

Answer (score -7):

If you want multiple CSS output , then you should not be using Tailwind for your project.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer. You're not answering the question, you're merely stating an opinion.

Comment: It's the correct opinion. Tailwind works so efficiently because it creates a single CSS file with every utility class your project contains.

If you start splitting it on a per-page basis, you end up with a huge overhead for duplicating the Tailwind setup classes and variables. Instead of 1x35KB CSS file, you'd have 10x30KB files.

Comment: @floodlitworld Not exactly. If compiling CSS file per template (maybe the OP also meant "templates", not literally "pages"), we can then enqueue corresponding CSS file for the template of the current page without duplicated classes

Comment: @floodlitworld there are numerous use reasons to output more than one CSS file. It's not the correct opinion.